# Redirect doesnt make authorization code for oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

Im trying to implement Oauth2 Code authorization flow.

I create a node js application and Im using simple-oauth2 npm repository.

Basically this is the code:

```
var credentials = {
    client: {
        id: '1yLCsmAfDF49nGmJLgDbHvB6bSca',
        secret: 'g2OKQ9isj2pcaextQdjx5xW3KoAa'
    },
    auth: {
        tokenPath: '/oauth/token',
        tokenHost: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
};


var OAuth2;



// Initial call redirecting to the Auth Server
app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {

    // Initialize the OAuth2 Library
    OAuth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create(credentials);

    // Authorization oauth2 URI
    var authorizationUri = OAuth2.authorizationCode.authorizeURL({
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
        scope: 'read+delete', // also can be an array of multiple scopes, ex. ['<scope1>, '<scope2>', '...']
        state: 'xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch'
    });

    res.redirect(authorizationUri);




});


// Callback endpoint parsing the authorization token and asking for the access token
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var code = req.query.code;

    console.log("code" + code);
    OAuth2.AuthCode.getToken({
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
    }, saveToken);

    function saveToken(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Access Token Error', error.message, error);
            res.json({ 'Access Token Error': error.message });
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            token = OAuth2.AccessToken.create(result);
            req.session.token = result;
            console.log("YOU REACH THIS")
        }
    }



});
```

So when I make the call:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth
```

It redirects to:

```
http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1yLCsmAfDF49nGmJLgDbHvB6bSca&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback&scope=read%2Bdelete&state=xcoiv98y2kd22vusuye3kch
```

Is this correct? As I understand it should redirect to something like :

```
http://localhost:3000/callback?code=kyaysdgflyasydfe
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally missunderstood the Oauth2 autorization code flow, the code must be generated in the server side and return it to the client. After that you can call /oauth/token